# How To Fix Incompatible Type

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Mason Wheeler wrote a very nice procedure to compare string lists, but I do not understand how to write the callback procedures TStringCompareProc.  Can some one help me get this to compile?

```
 type
     TStringCompareProc = procedure(const value: string; const data: TObject) of object;
     procedure StringListCompare(List1, List2: TStringList; matchProc: TStringEqualProc;
                                  list1Proc, list2Proc: TStringCompareProc; presorted: boolean = false);

    Usage:

    procedure TForm1.MatchProc(const value: string; const data: TObject);
    // match is found between the two lists
    begin
    //
    end;

    procedure TForm1.List1Proc(const value: string; const data: TObject);
    // when the first list contains a string not in the second list
    begin
    //
    end;

    procedure TForm1.List2Proc(const value: string; const data: TObject);
    // when the second list contains a string not in the first list
    begin
    //
    end;

    procedure TForm1.Compare1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
    MatchProc: TStringEqualProc;
    List1Proc: TStringCompareProc;
    List2Proc: TStringCompareProc;
    iValue: string;
    iData: ^PString;
    begin
    iFinalStringList := StringListCompare(iNewFilesStringList, iExistingFilesStringList,
              nil, nil, List1Proc(iValue, @iData), List2Proc(iValue, @iData), False); <- [DCC Error] Unit1.pas(1336): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TStringCompareProc' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'
    end;
```

Comment: At StackOverflow, you are not allowed to change your question to a new one. That will confuse people and make it difficult to find the question you are looking for. In addition, since this question has an accepted answer, no one will visit it and help you. Therefore you should restore this question to its original state and then create a *new* SO question with your new programming question. I have done the first part for you.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, I did not know how to handle that... meanwhile I solved the hints and warnings problem by removing     MatchProc: TStringEqualProc; List1Proc: TStringCompareProc; List2Proc: TStringCompareProc; vars... it now works... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only write `List1Proc` and `List2Proc` as arguments of `StringListCompare`. That is, write

```
iFinalStringList := StringListCompare(iNewFilesStringList,
  iExistingFilesStringList, nil, nil, List1Proc, List2Proc, False);
```

instead of

```
iFinalStringList := StringListCompare(iNewFilesStringList,
  iExistingFilesStringList, nil, nil, List1Proc(iValue, @iData),
  List2Proc(iValue, @iData), False);
```

Comment: Actually, another problem was StringListCompare is a procedure and not a function so I had to remove iFinalStringList := .
Thanks Andreas